# Return highest count value in SQL Query

Tags: sql, count

I have a table called ClassWithTest, that list all tests that has been assigned to a class. See below:

```
ClassNum  TestCode
111       EngTest
111       MatTest
111       SciTest
111       GerTest
222       TecTest
333       HisTest
333       LonTest
333       CodTest
333       SpaTest
333       SwmTest
```

Now, I want to run a query that returns the class with the most test to be taken. I've already started working on it and so far I've produced this:

```
SELECT ClassNum, COUNT(testCode)
FROM ClassWithTest
GROUP BY ClassNum;
```

It returns this result:

```
ClassNum  TestCode
111       4
222       1
333       5
```

The problem I have is I want to return just ClassNum 333 on its own, as that the class with the most test to be taken. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `order by` and a way to get the first row.  The ANSI SQL is:

```
SELECT ClassNum
FROM ClassWithTest
GROUP BY ClassNum
ORDER BY COUNT(testCode) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

In MySQL and SQLite, you would use `LIMIT 1` instead of the `FETCH` clause.  In SQL Server, you would use `SELECT TOP 1` instead of the `FETCH` clause.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, it works! I wasn't aware of that FETCH clause. Do you know a website that list these useful clauses? Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: @mrteeth . . . Whatever database you are using has pretty good documentation on its version of SQL.

Comment: Gordon, after looking at your profile, I noticed I've had your book on my amazon wishlist to buy in the future. :D

Comment: Hi, I've ran this and it doesn't work properly. I'm using SQLite, so when I run this with "LIMIT 1" (instead of "FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY"), it returns the 222, instead of 333. Any help?

Comment: @mrteeth . . . The problem was the order by`.  I had left out the `desc`, which I added yesterday.

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, it works now, thanks a lot for the help!